# Add new path to history stack without navigating in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, browser-history, next-router

Is there a way to programmatically add to the browser history stack such that next router will navigate to the newly added path on `router.back()`?

I have tried `window.history.pushState({}, '', "/my_new_route")` but it is not working correctly with next router. `router.back()` won't do anything on the first call. On the second call, it will then navigate to the route on the history stack previous to the custom added one, as expected.